# python selenium xpath solution

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

[image]

It is possible to do this:

- in the document I have several tables:

  ...

  `table id="odds_ou_159.5"`

  `table id="odds_ou_160.5"`

  `table id="odds_ou_161.5"`

  ...
- Tables contain several classes:

  ...

  `tr class = odd>`

  `tr class = odd>`

  ...
- class `odd` contain:

  `td class = bookmaker ...`

  `td> 161.5 </td>`

  `td class = kx`

  `td class = kx`

  td class = bonus

  ....
- class `kx` contain:

  `span class=" odds-wrap " eu="1.90"> 1.90`

Now I need to get content of class odd or just text from `<td> 161.5 </td>`, but my condition has to be `eu="1.90"`

Is it possible to get content of Ancestors (in my case class `odd`) depending on attribute values of Descendants (in my case `eu=1.90`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `XPath` and let me know in case of any issues:

```
//td[span[@eu="1.90"]]/preceding-sibling::td
```

Comment: @JakeSully, use single quotes for 1.90 when using in the code, as we use double quotes to provide XPath in findElement* methods.

Comment: Thank you, i wrote                                                                                   '//td[span[@class=" odds-wrap " and @eu="1.90"]]/preceding-sibling::td'                          and it works